# Adding items in myphp

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am having an issue when I trying to add multiple rows in myphp.  What I have is a function that when called it adds a textbox row to the website.  The problem is when I try to input the row into myphp it is only showing one row instead of all the rows that was added..  I am using a form to post to myphp..  I believe the issue is the name of the textbox when adding the row, the name is not changing so myphp is only inserting one row instead of muliple rows.  If anyone has any ideas on ways to fix this it will be greatly appreciated.  Here is my jquery code with the html code.

```
function displayResult() {
    var table=document.getElementById("customers");
    var row=table.insertRow(-1);
    row.innerHTML= '<td><input type ="text" name= "item" placeholder= "Item Description" > </td>'+
    '<td><input type ="text" name= "link" placeholder= "www.yourstorehere.com" > </td>'+
    '<td><input type ="text" name= "price" placeholder= "50.00" > </td>'+
    '<td><input type ="text" name= "comment" placeholder= "I would like it in blue.." > </td>'
}
```

And the php...

```
 // if form was submitted
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        // validate inputs
        if (empty($_POST["item"]))
        {
            apologize("You must provid an item.");
        }
        else if (empty($_POST["link"]))
        {
            apologize("You must provide a link or a place to purchase the item.");
        }
        else if (empty($_POST["price"]))
        {
            apologize("You must provide a price.");
        }

        // try to register user
        $results = query("INSERT INTO List (id,name,purpose,item,link,price,comment) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", $_SESSION["id"],$_POST["name"],$_POST["purpose"],$_POST["item"],$_POST["link"],$_POST["price"],$_POST["comment"]);
```

Comment: Is the displayResult function in php?

Comment: Sorry it is like mysql here is a link http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php

Comment: phpMyAdmin is not like mysql. It is a mysql front end written in php. A tool for administration.

Comment: Matt no it is in jquery..  It is called by a button in html. <button id="myButton" type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Insert a New Item</button>

Comment: Sorry thanks for letting me know about that difference Matt

Answer (score 0):

Try this

you can make dynamic array of names
to get it back when page is posted

keep an integer which increments for each row
suppose 
$index = 0 initially
increment it when new row is added.
And use this $index in names
for example you can give names like

```
    name='form[".$index."]["item"]'
    name='form[".$index."]["link"]'
    name='form[".$index."]["price"]'
    name='form[".$index."]["comment"]'
```

after each row increment index value by 1

after posting the page you will get array something like below

```
    Array(
    [0]=>Array
          (
             ['item']=>"some value"
             ['link']=>"some value"
             ['price']=>"some value"
             ['comment']=>"some value"
          )

    [1]=>Array
          (
             ['item']=>"some other value"
             ['link']=>"some other value"
             ['price']=>"some other value"
             ['comment']=>"some other value"
          )
    )
```

then at last you just need to rotate the loop to fetch all REQUEST values

I apologize you if I am wrong somewhere

Comment: Josh I understand what you are doing on the top of your code, because I thought about doing that, the issue is looping through the Array on the bottom part..  Maybe I am not understanding but what loop would you suggest on doing so?  A foreach loop on each array?

Comment: can you show me your $_REQUEST array? the above displayed array which will be inside your $_REQUEST array like $_REQUEST['form'] and this will hold above array which you need to rotate while generating query

Comment: Sorry I am fairly new at coding in php $_REQUEST array??

Comment: you can see the next answer , you will get two array $_POST and $_REQUEST when page is posted. $_POST will contain all data that are transferred through POST method of form and $_REQUEST array will contain all data posted through GET and POST both

Comment: Thanks Josh I understand what you are saying, but I am going to have to do some more research on what I want to do, your answer definitly gives me a good starting point.. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

After posting the page you will get $_REQUEST array something like this

```
    Array
    (
        ['form']=>Array
        (
           [0]=>Array
              (
                 ['item']=>"some value"
                 ['link']=>"some value"
                 ['price']=>"some value"
                 ['comment']=>"some value"
              )

        [1]=>Array
              (
                 ['item']=>"some other value"
                 ['link']=>"some other value"
                 ['price']=>"some other value"
                 ['comment']=>"some other value"
              )
        )
    )
```

Comment: on page where you are posting the form, there you will get $_REQUEST array or in your case we can aslo use $_POST array. I have shown you above array which will be formatted